# TransactionManagementError during call of `response_change`

Tags: django, python-3.x, transactions, django-orm, django-1.8

I'm working on Django 1.8 project, which has reach feature set in admin part. One of the `ModelAdmin` subclass overrides `response_change` method to handle action for `APPROVE` button. So, the code looks like the following:

```py
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        rel = obj.rel
        rel.title = obj.title
        rel.save()
        serialize('json', (rel, ))
        obj.approved = true
        obj.save()
        return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

And I'm getting the error on serialization line:

```
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 129, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 68, in serialize
    self.handle_m2m_field(obj, field)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 77, in handle_m2m_field
    for related in getattr(obj, field.name).iterator()]
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/python.py", line 76, in <listcomp>
    self._current[field.name] = [m2m_value(related)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 59, in execute
    self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 327, in validate_no_broken_transaction
    "An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

**An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.**

If I remove serialization line - the same error appears on `obj.save()` line. And the most strange part is that such error is raised on some objects and not raised on anothers.

What may cause that? How to fix?

Comment: You should probably move this code to the `save_model()` and `save_related()` methods. That way you can assign properties *before* the models are saved. The problem is that the entire form submission is an atomic transaction, in case an error occurs all database operations are reversed. So you can't save yourself during that transaction.

Comment: This probably means that somewhere in the code (likely `rel.save()`) you're catching a database exception and trying to continue. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) for the right way to do this.

Comment: So how could I catch errors?

Comment: So actually I'm 100% sure that error is happening during serialization.

Comment: The exception happens when you try to do a new database operation after the transaction has been spoiled. The error in the code you need to fix is wherever you're spoiling the transaction by catching the initial exception.